# How to access custom UIViewController in a UISplitViewController from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a custom customUIViewController in a UISplitViewController and want to access the instance of the customUiViewController from the detailView (which is another UIViewController inside the UISplitViewController) from another class; how can I do this?

CODE SNIP (Dont worry about the syntax; it is shorten up)

myAppDelegate.m

```
customViewController *masterView = [[customViewController alloc] init;
UINavigationController *NVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterView];

MYViewController *detailView = [[MyViewController alloc] init;

UISplitViewController *mySplit = [...];

mySplit.viewControllers = NSArray[...masterview,detailView,nil];

[window addSubView:mySplit view];
```

MyViewController.m

```
 -(void) someMethod {
        customViewController *myInstance = (customViewController)[self.splitViewController objectAtIndex:0]; ??
 // I think this just gets the outter UINavigationController
        [myInstance doSomething];
 }
```

customViewController.m

```
-(void) doSomething {
}
```

I want to be able to get access to customViewController to call the doSomething method. Both customViewController and myViewController is inside the same UISplitViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with the default UISplitView that XCode makes, you need to reference the AppDelegate to get the splitView's ivar:

```
YourAppDelegate *del = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
UISplitViewController *split = del.splitViewController;
NSArray *vcArray = split.viewControllers;
//left is objectAtIndex:0, right is objectAtIndex:1
```

Comment: Why I only have one in split.viewControllers. Work on iPad but not work on iPhone

Answer (score 5):

UIViewControllers have a splitViewController property so try using that to get a reference:

```
customViewController *myInstance = 
    (customViewController *)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers 
                                 objectAtIndex:0];
```

Index 0 is the left-side view controller in the split view controller.

**Edit:**
If the left-side view controller is a UINavigationController, then to get the root view controller of that, do this:

```
UINavigationController *nc = 
    (UINavigationController *)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers 
                                objectAtIndex:0];

customViewController *myInstance = 
    (customViewController *)[nc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: OK. Here is the another problem that I forgor to mention.

I already have the code you suggested and it works great.  The masterView is inside a UINavigationController

Comment: I think I did this and remember getting a warning the -customViewController may not respond to doSomething

Comment: Could be several reasons like doSomething was not declared in the customViewController.h file or spelling mistake (uppercase/lowercase), etc.

Comment: It just feels like it is not type casting to customViewController adn instead returns UIViewController

Comment: Do you mean it used to do that or it's still doing it?  Are you sure customViewController is the root of the nav controller?  It might be at a different index.  To get the current view controller showing in the nav controller (and it's a customViewController), then you can use `customViewController *myInstance = (customViewController *)nc.topViewController`.

Comment: ah. I will try that. Thanks.

When I instantiated the UINaviationController I did with initWithRootViewController and then tried accessing it by doing nc.rootViewController but I will try nc.topViewController

Comment: I tried using the topViewController and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Ok, using the reference through the app delegate probably works for you because the "self" in your case was not a UIViewController.  JustinXXVII's answer is better because it works regardless of where it's called from.

Comment: @Gank: Yes, as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/index.html) says: "In iOS 8 and later, you can use the UISplitViewController class on all iOS devices; **in previous versions of iOS, the class is available only on iPad**."